# Place picker closes quickly

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-geofence

I am using place picker in my project to let user add new locations. After user clicks the add new location button the Place picker interface opens up but the problem is that it opens up for only 1-2 seconds and closes. Below is my code of manifest ,mainactivity and of gradle.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.h.autoss2">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="my key" />

    <activity android:name="com.example.h.autoss2.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.example.h.autoss2.provider.PlaceContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.h.autoss2"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Constants
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 111;
private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

// Member variables
private PlaceListAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private boolean mIsEnabled;
private GoogleApiClient mClient;
private Geofencing mGeofencing;

/**
 * Called when the activity is starting
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState The Bundle that contains the data supplied in onSaveInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the recycler view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.places_list_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new PlaceListAdapter(this, null);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.enable_switch);
    mIsEnabled = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(getString(R.string.setting_enabled), false);
    onOffSwitch.setChecked(mIsEnabled);
    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.setting_enabled), isChecked);
            mIsEnabled = isChecked;
            editor.commit();
            if (isChecked) mGeofencing.registerAllGeofences();
            else mGeofencing.unRegisterAllGeofences();
        }

    });


           mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

    mGeofencing = new Geofencing(this, mClient);

}

/***
 * Called when the Google API Client is successfully connected
 *
 * @param connectionHint Bundle of data provided to clients by Google Play services
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle connectionHint) {
    refreshPlacesData();
    Log.i(TAG, "API Client Connection Successful!");
}

/***
 * Called when the Google API Client is suspended
 *
 * @param cause cause The reason for the disconnection. Defined by constants CAUSE_*.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API Client Connection Suspended!");
}

/***
 * Called when the Google API Client failed to connect to Google Play Services
 *
 * @param result A ConnectionResult that can be used for resolving the error
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.e(TAG, "API Client Connection Failed!");
}

public void refreshPlacesData() {
    Uri uri = PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (data == null || data.getCount() == 0) return;
    List<String> guids = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        guids.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_ID)));
    }
    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mClient,
            guids.toArray(new String[guids.size()]));
    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            mAdapter.swapPlaces(places);
            mGeofencing.updateGeofencesList(places);
            if (mIsEnabled) mGeofencing.registerAllGeofences();
        }
    });
}


public void onAddPlaceButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.need_location_permission_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    try {

        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("GooglePlayServices Not Available [%s]", e.getMessage()));
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("GooglePlayServices Not Available [%s]", e.getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("PlacePicker Exception: %s", e.getMessage()));
    }
}


/***
 * Called when the Place Picker Activity returns back with a selected place (or after canceling)
 *
 * @param requestCode The request code passed when calling startActivityForResult
 * @param resultCode  The result code specified by the second activity
 * @param data        The Intent that carries the result data.
 */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
        if (place == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No place selected");
            return;
        }

        String placeID = place.getId();

        // Insert a new place into DB
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_ID, placeID);
        getContentResolver().insert(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        // Get live data information
        refreshPlacesData();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Initialize location permissions checkbox
    CheckBox locationPermissions = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.location_permission_checkbox);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationPermissions.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        locationPermissions.setChecked(true);
        locationPermissions.setEnabled(false);
    }

    // Initialize ringer permissions checkbox
    CheckBox ringerPermissions = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ringer_permissions_checkbox);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Check if the API supports such permission change and check if permission is granted
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 && !nm.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        ringerPermissions.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        ringerPermissions.setChecked(true);
        ringerPermissions.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void onRingerPermissionsClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onLocationPermissionClicked(View view) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
}
```

}

Build.gradle (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.h.autoss2"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
}
```

Comment: You have `Google Places API for Android` api enabled in the developer console? Check here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/

Comment: @Danial Nugent Yes sir it is enabled

Comment: Check your logs, it might have a clue.  Usually this problem is due to misconfigured api key.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I was using the google maps Api instead of places api.... and now I have enabled places api for my key it solved the problem.... thanks for you help sir.